# How to inject promise array inside observable array

Tags: javascript, angular, promise, rxjs, observable

I'm building a user menu based on authentication and everything work, but I have part of that menu I get it from an API `getMainCategories()` a `promise` type method.

I need to inject the coming data from that method inside my menu array on a specific object;

**Here:**

```js
let menu: any = [
  ...
  {
    text: 'categories',
    icon: 'flaticon-2-squares',
    children: [] // I need to inject the categories here
  },
  ...
];
```

On the code below you will notice that I have converted the promise `getMainCategories` into `observable` but I can't figure out what next.

**My Menu code:**

```js
getMenu() {

  const mainCategories = from(this.woo.getMainCategories());

  let menu: any = [
    {
      text: 'home',
      icon: 'flaticon-home',
      path: '/tabs/home'
    },
    {
      text: 'categories',
      icon: 'flaticon-2-squares',
      children: []
    },
    {
      text: 'cart',
      icon: 'flaticon-shopping-cart',
      path: '/tabs/cart'
    },
    {
      text: 'chechout',
      icon: 'flaticon-shopping-bag',
      path: '/checkout'
    }
  ];

  const loggedInMenu = [
    {
      text: 'My Account',
      icon: 'flaticon-login',
      path: '/tabs/profile'
    }
  ];

  const loggedOutMenu = [
    {
      text: 'login',
      icon: 'flaticon-login',
      path: '/login'
    },
    {
      text: 'register',
      icon: 'flaticon-login',
      path: '/register'
    }
  ];

  const menu$ = this.isUserLoggedIn.pipe(
    switchMap(
      status => {
        if (status) {
          return of(menu.concat(loggedInMenu))
        } else {
          return of(menu.concat(loggedOutMenu))
        }
      }
    )
  );

  return menu$;

}
```

Comment: What is it what you need to do with your code? it is not clear

Comment: Sorry, about that, 

I need the coming data array from that `promise` method `getMainCategories` to be injected or pushed inside  a specific object with `text: 'categories'` on menu array from the code above

Comment: Why do you want to convert the Promise into an Observable first? If you just want to assign the value returned by a Promise to a local variable you can use `then`.

Comment: @fridoo I don't know why I didn't do that :"D
I think because angular depends on  RXJS a lot, My mind didn't think for other ways :"D 

any way thanks, bro I fixed it by just `then`.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what "of" is. But I think you may want to let menu.children.concat(loggedXXXMenu) rather than menu.concat.

Comment: of is return data as observable. and what I need is? on the object with text `categories` I need to inject the categories that comes from `getMainCategories` a `promise` method into children `property`

Comment: As I don't use "of" I don't know the syntax. If it is a promise, then it can be promise().then((result)=>{menu.children.concat(result)};); Then the value of menu looks like "menu:{xxx:xxx, children:[valueOfResult] }"